# "takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given" while finding minimum of function

Tags: python, error-handling

I want to find minimum of function using *fmin*, but I got the following error:

```
TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

The problematic piece of code is the following:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fmin

g = lambda alpha: np.sum(np.square(np.subtract(D, (avec[0]-alpha*grad)*f((avec[1]-alpha*grad),y))))

b = fmin(g,0.0)
```

Could you tell me how I can fix this please?

The whole code is here:

```
from scipy.optimize import fmin
from scipy import interpolate
import numpy as np



Emax = 10;
bins = 200;

x = np.linspace(1, Emax, num = Emax, dtype=np.int)   #create grid of indexes
y = np.linspace(1, bins, num = bins, dtype=np.int)
z = np.random.rand(bins, Emax)                       # response matrix   
f = interpolate.interp2d(x,y,z, kind='cubic')        # make the matrix continious

D= np.zeros(bins) 
D = 1*f(1.5, y) + 3*f(2.5, y)   # signal

iterations = 1000
step = 1e-5

avec = np.array([1.0,2.0])   # chosen starting parameters 
grad = np.array([0.0,0.0])
chix_current = np.arange(iterations, dtype=float)

#gradient unfolding

for i in range(0, iterations):
    fx = avec[0]*f(avec[1], y)     # evaluation in every layer
    chi = np.square(np.subtract(D,fx))    #chi function  
    chi_a = np.square(np.subtract(D,  (avec[0]+step)*f(avec[1],y))) 
    chi_b = np.square(np.subtract(D,  avec[0]*f((avec[1]+step),y)))   

    chisquared = np.sum(chi)
    chisquared_a = np.sum(chi_a)
    chisquared_b = np.sum(chi_b)

    grad[0] = np. divide(np.subtract(chisquared_a, chisquared), step)                 
    grad[1] = np.divide(np.subtract(chisquared_b, chisquared), step)        



    g= lambda alpha: np.sum(np.square(np.subtract(D,  (avec[0]-alpha*grad)*f((avec[1]-alpha*grad),y)) ))
    b= fmin(g,(0.0))


    avec= np.subtract(avec, 1e5*grad )
```

Eventually I just need to know the value of alpha when the function g is at its minimum and use it instead of 1e5 in the last line.

Comment: Please post code that is reproducible. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What are `D`, `avec[0]`, `alpha`, `grad`, `f((avec[1]-alpha*grad)`, `y`?

Comment: `f((avec[1]-alpha*grad),y)` is calling your `lambda` with two parameters: `(avec[1]-alpha*grad)` and `y`. More importantly, I'm not sure this recursive code is going to do what you expect.

Comment: Readability helps us troubleshoot your code. Try to reorganize before posting and add context so people can understand it as best as possible.

Comment: thanks for your comments, the code is added

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not so clear, some methods and variables are ambiguous.

From what you given, it seems that lambda function `f()` should take 1 parameter, but inside `f()` you call `f()` again recursively, but the inner `f()` takes 2 parameters, I think it is a typo.

Try to rename your lambda method to another name without conflict, such as `g`:

```
g = lambda alpha: np.sum(np.square(np.subtract(D, (avec[0]-alpha*grad)*f((avec[1]-alpha*grad),y))))
b = fmin(g,0.0)
```

Comment: thanks, I renamed the function, still have the error though

Comment: If you still have the same error, then it is the issue of your inner f(), it should take 1 parameter, but here you give 2 parameters, You'd better to check the definition of f(). If you have new error, please show us.

Comment: what is avec[2] and avec[3]? avec is a 2 values list. g = lambda alpha: np.sum(np.square(np.subtract(D, (avec[0]-alpha*grad)*f((avec[1]-alpha*grad),y))))

Comment: don't mind these values, I have already erased them from the function.. avec has 2 elements.
I copied it to here from another code by mistake